# Reverse image search with Google images

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to search where an image is located only using Google Maps, like specify that it is Google Maps. This is the image I am trying to find.

[image]

Comment: There ist an OSINT (**O**pen **S**ource **INT**elligence) community specialized in verifying and confirming the location of pictures, especially from war zones like currently in Ukraine. I would have a look to the methodologies they use. A random example is Benjamin Pittet on Twiter @COUPSURE - more satellite images, but there are others working with pictures from the ground

Comment: See e.g. https://youtu.be/RoqWbpZUOSo or https://youtu.be/CWMF8Bx_Lyk or https://www.skopenow.com/resource-center/image-based-osint-investigations-tips-techniques or https://craighays.com/how-an-investigator-can-find-your-location-from-one-photograph/ etc. Many more, search for "open source intelligence verify location picture" and so on

Comment: You should first start with what you know about the picture: where do you have it from? What place could it be: worldwide? a specific country (the US? Australi?)? A certain state, region or town? What does the type of car, houses, vegetation say about the area? Do you have a better resolution/larger image size? Can the vehicle's registration plate be identified, any streetname or housenumber be read? The more info you have, the easier it is. You should provide all kind of information you have to you question if you expect an answer.